# Preventing multiple toggling at a same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i prevent slidedown and slide up of a sub menu at the same time?My navigation has a menu and one of the menus has sub menu.When i click On the menu which has sub menu , The sub menu opens,closes about 2 times and finally closes but there was only one click.It happens in mobile devices.SO take a look at my codes

### HTML

```
<ul class="nav-menu align-right">
  <li class="current"><a href="index.html#header">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html#about-us">about us</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="extra">Extra</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="blog-three.html">blog grid 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-four.html">blog grid 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html#contact">contact</a></li></li>   
</ul>
```

### And js

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() < 1000){
       $('.nav-menu li a').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(200, 'easeInExpo');
          $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(200, 'easeInExpo'); 
       });
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the events everytime the window is resized so they will trigger multipe times. If you chamge to this it should work [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ubq9wtxf/1/)

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('.nav-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        if($(window).width() < 1000){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(200, 'easeInExpo');
            $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(200, 'easeInExpo'); 
        }
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind the events multiple times! Every time the page resizes you keep adding click events. So they will keep piling on.

You need to unbind the events if you are going to do it that way.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('.nav-menu li a').off("click");  //there are better ways, but it will work
    if($(window).width() < 1000){
       $('.nav-menu li a').click(function(e) {
       /* rest of logic */
       });
    }
});
```

other option is to bind once and do the width check inside of the click method.

```
$(function(){    
    $('.nav-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        if($(window).width() >= 1000) return true;
        /* rest of logic */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since on load and resize you are binding the click method so it will be bind twice. It better to use only one method. If you are doing it in resize every time you resize it will be bind again and again